# ¿Cómo adjuntar un modelo c# a una petición a una api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Tengo un proyecto asp.net mvc que realiza una solicitud a una api, la cual recibe un modelo y no sé como enviarlo, de momento mi código es

```
minodelo modelo = new mimodelo();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://servidor/");
                    //HTTP GET
                    var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/ApiTest"/*debería ir aquí*/);
                    responseTask.Wait();

                    var result = responseTask.Result;
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserSession>();
                        readTask.Wait();
                        us = readTask.Result;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Pues, depende de la API, puedes enviar los datos por `QueryString` o por el `body`  del `request`

Comment: No lo tomes como ley, más bien como una práctica común: Cuando traes información (`GET`), generalmente enviarás los parámetros en el `QueryString`. Cuando subas información, u objetos para una operación CRUD (`POST`), utiliza el `body`

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviarlo como querystring, por lo que puedes utilizar este método para serializar tu objeto:

```
public string GetQueryString(object obj) {
  var properties = from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                   where p.GetValue(obj, null) != null
                   select p.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.GetValue(obj, null).ToString());

  return String.Join("&", properties.ToArray());
}
```

Entonces tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
string queryString = GetQueryString(modelo);
var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/ApiTest" + queryString);
```